# How to mount (bind) in a one-way writing fashion

Tags: mount, proxy, bind-mount

In case you needed to know, I'm on a GNU+Linux distro with kernel version *5.5.5*.

So, suppose I have a directory named  **base**. Further suppose this directory only contains one empty file, named **a**.
Ideally, I'd like to *fork* that directory retaining its content into a new directory named **fork**. Then, I'd write something into the file **a** and, moreover, create a new empty file named **b** (inside of **fork**).

The expected behavior I'd like to achieve is that **base** directory contents remains unaltered (i.e. empty file **a** only), meanwhile changes made in **fork** directory persist.

This is the simplest example I could give you, keep in mind that **base** might contain a lot of files, so the purpose of this is just to avoid copying those files when possible.

Do you happen to know if this is possible? If so, how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [OverlayFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS), or on some distributions the still available [aufs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs).

Here's the description of OverlayFS in the [Linux kernel documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt?h=v5.4#n4):

> ## Overlay Filesystem
>
> This document describes a prototype for a new approach to providing
>   overlay-filesystem functionality in Linux (sometimes referred to as
>   union-filesystems).  An overlay-filesystem tries to present a
>   filesystem which is the result over overlaying one filesystem on top
>   of the other.

Here's a working example with OverlayFS. It requires two additional directories, one to keep the permanent alterations: all data will be written there, so disk space will be consumed there, and an empty working directory in the same filesystem.

So let's say you have those directories that can be in three different filesystems mounted as `/fs1`, `/fs2` and `/fs3` (all can of course be on the same filesystem):

```
/fs1/base
/fs2/delta
/fs2/work
/fs3/fork
```

As documented in the previous link, you mount the final merged view (`/fs3/fork`) with:

```
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/fs1/base,upperdir=/fs2/delta,workdir=/fs2/work /fs3/fork
```

And that's it. You'll have to read the documentation to know about limitations (eg: when NFS is involved etc.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot